# JavaScript Input Multi-Validation

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, xslt-1.0

In JavaScript, I am trying to check an input that must accept only 11 numeric characters or 17 alphabetic characters.

I can do one thing or the other, but I cannot do it all together, and I really do not know how to solve it.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take some time to complete the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the help topic [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting. Good questions normally have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, StackOverflow has an [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) with lots of information. Thanks.

Comment: You can do that with javascript events and regex. But in order to help you we need you to at least try and when you get stuck, then show us the code you're doing and we'll help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

-fetch the input value:-

> For ex:- If you are using Id:-
>       document.getElementById('textbox_id').value *to get the value of desired box*

**Then you can use regex :-**

**to match 10 digits**

```
var str='01234567891';
console.log(/^\d{11}$/.test(str));
```

**to match 17 alphanumeric Character**

```
var reg= new RegExp('[a-zA-Z0-9]{17}');
console.log(reg.test("1234567890qwertyu"))
```

**You can OR both to check if the desired condition is matched**

## Putting all together

```
var str = document.getElementById('textbox_id').value
var reg= new RegExp('[a-zA-Z0-9]{17}');


if(reg.test(str) || /^\d{11}$/.test(str)){

}
else{

}
```